# Some doubts about bluemix bluelist application

Tags: android, cloud, ibm-cloud, cloudant, ibm-mobile-services

After fight with Bluemix bluelist mobile application, I was able to put it to work. But now I don't know if it is not working properly or if I need to some more system configuration. So, here are some questions.

1. In the Log option in Dashboard I only see new messages when the app is starting. After that, no more messages even when I am adding/removing items. Is that correct?
2. In IBM Push Notification, I can send notification to my cell phone but when I go to Monitoring option, there is nothing registered in Push Performance. Should I have some data regarding to notifications sent to my device? Well, at least I can see my device subscribed.
3. In Cloudant NoSQL DB, I see 2 databases: one is the app user and the other is for the application? I don't know. I was thinking to find the database records here. Where is my data? Need I create a Data Warehouse to see my database? Or the data is not being stored in cloud?
   Sorry about the questions but I have read lots of docs and tried to run samples to understand how things works but I am still a bit lost.
   Regards

Answer (score 0):

For #1, yes that is correct. The Log option shows you logs from your Bluemix hosted Node,js runtime. If you'd like to enable more logging for your Node app you will need to edit the Node.js code with `console.log()` and `cf push` your new code up to Bluemix.

To enable and/or persist logging and analytics from your mobile app see [Application Monitoring](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobileaccess/app-monitoring.html), [Enabling, configuring, and using Logger](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobileaccess/app-monitoring-logger.html), and [Gathering usage analytics](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobileaccess/app-monitoring-gathering-analytics.html).

For #2, I am noticing the same thing and am investigating further. I will have an update for you on this subject shortly. If anything, the updates are delayed due to the interaction between the native push notification services (GCM and APNs) and the Bluemix Push Notifications service.

For #3, your data is there and is obfuscated intentionally. The Bluelist app is designed to sync with your Bluemix Cloudant data but it may be difficult to find in the dashboard. If there are no failures before, during, or after pulling down the list on your mobile device to sync with your Cloudnant data, then you can trust the data you see on your device is going to exist in your Bluemix Cloudant instance. You'll notice the Bluelist app pulls down any existing data in your Cloudant instance upon successful login as well.